# Bot Framework Composer variable equivalent

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

When creating an Azure bot, the variable turn.activity.text I used in Bot Framework Composer is equivalent to turnContext.Activity.Text when coding in Visual Studio. I want to ask a question that what is equivalent to user.name or user.age in Bot Framework Composer when coding in Visual Studio?

[Bot Framwork Composer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOQeB.png)

[Visual Studio Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh6ID.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bot needs to maintain user state to track the user's answers.

Have you had a chance to check out sample [/45.state-management/](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/45.state-management)? It demonstrates how to save user and conversation data in a bot. The bot maintains conversation state to track and direct the conversation and ask the user questions.

The above sample is available in other programming languages such as C#, JavaScript, Python, Java from the following link:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples